# I'm getting an error on android studio, it shows could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I'm newbie working on app development using flutter .I tried manually downloading gradle:4.5.2.zip file and locating it to gradle location path on android studio ,but couldn't able to resolve the problem so pls help me

Comment: did you updated gradle files

Comment: You should *not* have to download anything.  SUGGESTION: perhaps the simplest, fastest solution might be to simply reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932083/how-do-i-upgrade-gradle/1067526#1067526

Answer (score 1):

You can try running "flutter clean" once and then rebuild the project. This will work I think.